# How to calculate the total days for reservation in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table the stores vehicles reservations for each record I have `dateFrom` "the reservation start date" and a `dateTo` "the reservation end date"

I am trying to write a query to calculate the total of day each vehicles was booked and also the total of revenue each vehicles generates.

The business rule are are the following

1. If the `dateFrom` and `dateTo` are in the same day then that is considered 1 days
2. If the reservation is from `2013-05-25` to `2013-06-06` then then 7 days go to the month of may and 5 days go to the month of june here is a break down of this logic

> ```
> 2013-05-25 - 2013-05-26 (May)
> 2013-05-26 - 2013-05-27 (May)
> 2013-05-27 - 2013-05-28 (May)
> 2013-05-28 - 2013-05-29 (May)
> 2013-05-29 - 2013-05-30 (May)
> 2013-05-30 - 2013-05-31 (May)
> 2013-05-31 - 2013-06-01 (**May**)
> 2013-06-01 - 2013-06-02 (June)
> 2013-06-02 - 2013-06-02 (June)
> 2013-06-03 - 2013-06-02 (June)
> 2013-06-04 - 2013-06-02 (June)
> 2013-06-05 - 2013-06-02 (June)
> ```

This is an example on how the calculation should work.

For the revenue I am suppose to calculate the average daily rent by dividing the total revenue by the total rented days then multiplying the daily average by the total day that fits this range

This is my current query but it is not calculating the today days correctly.
so in the above example if we assume that the total revenue for the whole reservation is $1500
then the average daily rent is `$1500/12 = $125`

so since the range that we are calculating is `"2013-06-01 00:00:00"` to `"2013-06-16 23:59:59"`, the this vehicle should display total days are 5 and total revenue is $625.
More, if the range was `2013-05-01 00:00:00` to `2013-05-31 23:59:59` then the same vehicle will have  total of 7 days and total revenue of $875

The following is my current query in where I am trying to calculate the differences.

```
SELECT rs.vehicle_id,
    ROUND(SUM(


        CASE
        WHEN (rs.dateFrom BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00" AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59")
        AND (rs.dateTo BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00"  AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59")
        THEN (rs.totalRent + rs.totalTax)

        WHEN rs.dateTo BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00"  AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        AND rs.dateFrom < "2013-06-01 00:00:00"
        THEN ( ( (rs.totalRent + rs.totalTax) / CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) END) * (DATEDIFF(rs.dateTo, "2013-06-01 00:00:00")) )

        WHEN rs.dateFrom BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00" AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        AND rs.dateTo > "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        THEN ( ( (rs.totalRent + rs.totalTax) / CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) END) * (DATEDIFF( "2013-06-16 23:59:59",rs.dateFrom)+1) )

        WHEN rs.dateFrom < "2013-06-01 00:00:00" AND rs.dateTo > "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        THEN ( ( (rs.totalRent + rs.totalTax) / CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) END) * (DATEDIFF( "2013-06-16 23:59:59", "2013-06-01 00:00:00") +1) )

        ELSE 0 END 

 )) AS income,


SUM(

        CASE
        WHEN (rs.dateFrom BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00" AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59")
        AND (rs.dateTo BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00"  AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59")
        THEN CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF( rs.dateTo,rs.dateFrom) END

        WHEN rs.dateTo BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00"  AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        AND rs.dateFrom < "2013-06-01 00:00:00"
        THEN CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(rs.dateTo, "2013-06-01 00:00:00") = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (DATEDIFF(rs.dateTo, "2013-06-01 00:00:00")) END

        WHEN rs.dateFrom BETWEEN "2013-06-01 00:00:00" AND "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        AND rs.dateTo > "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        THEN CASE WHEN DATEDIFF( "2013-06-16 23:59:59",rs.dateFrom) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (DATEDIFF( "2013-06-16 23:59:59",rs.dateFrom))  END

        WHEN rs.dateFrom < "2013-06-01 00:00:00" AND rs.dateTo > "2013-06-16 23:59:59"
        THEN DATEDIFF( "2013-06-16 23:59:59", "2013-06-01 00:00:00")+1 

        ELSE 0 END 

 ) AS days       
FROM reservation AS rs
WHERE rs.reservationStatus IN (2,3)
GROUP BY rs.Vehicle_id
```

The problem is that the query is not calculating the total days correctly. Can somebody help me with this please?

The following is a sample of my code

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cbc/3 for testing with data

Comment: Are you looking for one number, the monthly rent for a specific car for a specific month, or multiple numbers, the rent, by month, for a specific car?

Comment: One number per vehicle per range. so for vehicle #1 i need the total reserved days with in the selected range and for the same vehicles the total revenue. so if I have total of 10 vehicles then I should get a total of 10 records

Comment: I'm taking a stab at this, but I'm still having a tough time trying to visualize the problem that you're describing.  You've discussed several issues, splitting rent between May and June, counting the number of days, calculating the rent/tax for a date range based on an average rent/tax.  Could you post some data, and exactly what you would expect to to see from that data?  Ideally, you would create the table in sqlFiddle.com

Comment: @BrianHoover  I am sorry it took me a while to get back to you. I had problems.  I prepared a sqlFiddle for you to review http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6cbc/3  the results should be $150 and not $300 and it should be 1 Day and not 2 Days

Comment: Ok.  I'm starting to get it.  Its complicated.  But what I'm seeing is that it should be two days.  You are looking at everything between May 31st at 12:01 AM and June 1st at 11:59PM.  Why would the algorithm think that it should only apply 1 day from reservation 1483?

Comment: It is a business rule. So I have to make the algorithm to fit the business rules.

Comment: May 31 - June 1 is (1 Day not 2 days.) Think about it is someone booked a car from May 31 and returned it on June 1 then he had it for 1 day

Comment: Sure, I get that.  The date range, for that case, would be 2013-05-31 00:00:00 and 2013-06-01 00:00:00.  That would be one day.

Comment: So why is the results counting 2 days here? And how to fix it is where I need help. It has been a challenge for me.

Comment: Can you post a few sample entries with your desired output, the sqlfiddle example contains a lot of un-needed fields that makes it harder to understand

Answer (score 1):

There is no overlap in intervals(i.e. for a car you have some logic to ensure that it is not reserved multiple times?

If you are looking for the entire history, you can certainly just sum up the invidual lengths of each reservation. Do you want some per-month breakdown?

```
SELECT SUM( TO_DAYS(dateTo)-TO_DAYS(dateFrom) +1 ) AS sum_days_reserved FROM table
```

Comment: How is this going to help me calculate the total days based on the business rules?

Answer (score 1):

So I've taken a stab at it. Let's start with the code.  The explanation comes later.

```
SELECT rs.vehicle_id,
  round(sum(datediff(least(rs.dateTo, '2013-06-02 00:00:00'),
                 greatest(rs.dateFrom, '2013-05-31 00:00:00'))*(totalRent + totalTax)*datediff(least(rs.dateTo, '2013-06-02 00:00:00'),
                 greatest(rs.dateFrom, '2013-05-31 00:00:00'))/totalDays))
        AS income,
  sum(datediff(least(rs.dateTo, '2013-06-02 00:00:00'),
                 greatest(rs.dateFrom, '2013-05-31 00:00:00')))
        AS days
FROM reservation rs
  WHERE rs.dateFrom < '2013-06-02 00:00:00'
    AND rs.dateTo > '2013-05-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY rs.vehicle_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72a508/4)

The most important thing that you have to think about is whether the date range is inclusive or exclusive.  So, if you want the amount from 5/31 to 6/1, does this mean that you want to include revenue from 6/1 or does this mean that you are only looking for revenue on 5/31.  This concept trips a lot of developers up.  From your comments and posts, I'm assuming that you want the date range to be exclusive.

In the case I created, the window goes from 5/31 at 00:00:00 to 6/1 at 00:00.  If you want it to be inclusive, you could end the window at 6/2 00:00:00.

The rest of the solution is just a little more elegant way of doing what you were already doing.  You can look for a date window by seeing if the start date is less than the end of the date range and the end date is greater than the start of the date range.

Then you can calculate the actual amount of days in the window by looking at the maximum of the dateFrom and the windowStart, as well as the minimum of the dateTo and the windowEnd.

Comment: thanks for your time with this. For the income it should be the the average rent* count of days. If you change the range on your solution to be 2013-06-01 00:00:00 to 2013-06-01 23:59:59 then you will get a 0 for days and for income. also if I have a rest starting from 2013-05-01 00:0:00 to 2013-06-28 00:00:00 this record will be ignored.

Comment: I've clarified my answer.  You're right. For a single day, it always has to go to the 00:00:00 of the next day, so that should always be your ending point.  You should never use 23:59:59.  It does pick up the reservation that you mentioned, and I've put that into the new SQLFiddle

Comment: will the date are generated from a datetimepicker. for if the user select date range from 2013-06-01 to 2013-06-30 then you need to report on every day from 2013-06-02 to 2013-06-30 if the reservation datefrom is less than 2013-06-01 but if the datefrom is = to 2013-06-01 then report from 2013-06-01. same thing for the end date. if the dateTo is <= 2013-06-30 then report until 2013-06-30 but if the dateTo is greater than 2013-06-30 then report until 2013-07-01. I hope i am making sense because it is very complected.

Comment: Why, if the user enters 6/1 to 6/30 do you want to show reservations from 6/2 to 6/30?  Why if the user enter 6/20 as the last date do you show until 6/30?  why if the user entered 7/10 as the from date do you show reservations until 7/1?  I'm not understanding your date logic here.

Comment: Well it all depends on when the reservation started. if customer A has a reservation from 2013-05-28 - 2013-06-02-2013 then we should only include 1 day for this record if the user select a range of 2013-06-01-2013 - 2013-06-30. but if the user select 2013-05-01 - 2013-05-31 for a date range then the system should capture only 4 days which are the 28th-29th, 29th - 30th, 30th - 31st, and 31st - 1st the same logic apply to the income.

Comment: "2013-05-28 - 2013-06-02-2013"? I'm confused.